# css gliding text by resizing window

Tags: css

some days ago i saw a webside where the text (`padding-left: 5%`) glided to another position when i resized the window. normally the position is changed "hard" (means when i make the window 100px wider, the position is 5px more away from left), but there it really glides to this new position.

first i thought it would be a js library, so i tried deactivating javascript, but even after this it worked, so i think it must be css-based? has anybody a hint how can i make this too?

Comment: Can you check your browser history, and send us the website link?

Comment: i think it was torbenleuschner.de

Comment: Sorry, I don't see what you are referencing even with Javascript turned off, although it may be difficult to understand exactly where you meant on the page.  Can you say where in the page you were examining the element?

Comment: when i change my browser size from 1440(width) to 700, the text is gliding (not static)

Comment: The text is supposed to move when the window is resized.  If you are commenting about how it is somewhat animated when moving, you are likely interested in understanding the `transition` technique in CSS.  Check out :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this with purely css you need to use media queries and css transitions.

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yt54ymhv/) (Try resizing the results pane quickly)

The key parts:

```
.gliding-text {
    padding-left: 0px;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
@media (min-width: 200px) {
    .gliding-text {
        padding-left: 10px;
     }
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
    .gliding-text {
        padding-left: 100px;
    }
}
```

The media queries act as breakpoints for when the transitions are applied. In the example I made the padding-left property is changed when the window is 200px-499px and then again when the window is 500px+. This triggers the padding-left property to change and the css transition is applied. This is a simple example of the technique you described.

Checkout [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and [css transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)